# Combine implicit arguments and partial application

Tags: coq

My function `foo` has an implicit argument coming from its section :

```
Section Foosec.
  Context {A: Type}.
  Parameter foo : nat -> A -> A.
End Foosec.
```

Outside of the section, `@foo` has type `∀ A : Type, ℕ → A → A`.  Is there a way to tell Coq to generate a function of type `ℕ → ∀ A : Type, A → A` instead? i.e. to insert the implicit argument as late as possible? It would make the definition of partial applications much simpler.

Or, with a more pragmatic approach, is there something like `@(foo 1)`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there is no way of swapping the order of the arguments generated by the section mechanism in Coq. Maybe if you tried to give more details about how you want to use this partially applied function we could find ways of circumvent this limitation...

Comment: Thanks. Let's rather say that `foo` has type `nat -> list A -> list A`. If I want to pass `foo 1` to a function `appF : (∀ A, list A → list A) -> Type` then I need to write `appF (fun A => @foo A 1)`, which lacks of  conciseness.

Comment: @pjm Yes, it is true that that syntax is a bit clumsy. Could you be more specific about what `appF` and `foo` represent in your application? It is a bit unusual (though certainly possible) to take polymorphic types as parameters, like you are doing.

Comment: Here `appF` applies its first argument to a data structure containing some lists of different types, that's why polymorphism is needed.  I managed to solve the problem by weakening the definition `appF : ∀ B, (∀ A, B → list A → list A) → B → ...` so that the partial application is now written `appF (@foo) 1`.  I still believe that an `@` working on terms (not only identifiers) would be very handy.